# json_encode dropping array_values key?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am working in PHP and have an issue with `json_encode()`. The process wipes the inital "key" that was set by the "array_values" command as shown below.

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(5) { 
        ["ID"]=> string(4) "2679" [
        "PackageName"]=> "Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB2965065)" 
        ["Description"]=> string(262) "Install this update to resolve issues in Windows." 
        ["KB"]=> string(7) "2965065" 
        ["Repo"]=> string(21) "Windows Update Server" 
}

$packages = array_values($this->control->fetchPackageTables($this->input->get("platform")));             

[
    {
        "ID":"2679",
        "PackageName":"Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB2965065)",
        "Description":"Install this update to resolve issues in Windows.", 
        "KB":"2965065",
        "Repo":"Windows Update Server"
    }
]
```

I have tried looping with a foreach through the array and setting a number but it still gets dropped. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: array_values dont set anything, it just return values of an array. Remove array_values and You gonna have that key.

Comment: I didnt get it, what is it dropping. what is the initial key in question

Comment: Where do you call `json_encode()`.

Comment: pretty much the sole purpose of `array_values` is to strip off the keys and return a numbered array

Comment: Your JSON is 100% correct.  It is *exactly* as it should be.  `[]` is an array in JSON.  Arrays are numeric, and automatically start at 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON does not support associative arrays.

Arrays in JSON / Javascript consist only of numbered indexes. Associative arrays will be converted to objects/properties.

There is nothing getting dropped. `[ ]` indicates an array. `{ }` indicates an object. You have `one` object in the array.

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding this as an answer as I currently can't comment, and was helpful for myself. If you find that a segment of your json is being encoded as an array instead of an object (e.g.:the key's are being dropped).

You can add JSON_FORCE_OBJECT like this:
    `json_encode($foo,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`
This will force everything to be encoded as an object, preserving all keys.

You can find more flags here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason why it is dropping the indexes is because they are indexed by number so when encoding it just thinks it does not need the keys you could try making your keys into strings as opposed to integers so the encoding doesn't wipe them.